# PHP Doctrine2 property inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have this scenario.

Entity File, with some usefull properties like path for file and others.

Entity Image, which is file too, so it have same properties, but contains some more as width,height...

My implementation looks like this

Entity File.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class File
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="file_seq")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fileName;
    .
    .
    .
```

Entity Image.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="images")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Image extends File
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="image_seq")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;
    .
    .
    other properties...
}
```

Everything works just fine except of property id. Table images is not joined to image_seq(which also is not even created) and takes nextval from file_seq. Is there any way how to get this scenario fully working and inherit entities? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect situation for implementing a [mapped superclass](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

Comment: I hope there is another solution. Why doctrine maps id property annotations from parent table when I override it in Image.php?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell doctrine what type of inheritance you would like to apply. Read [the docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) for the different strategies Doctrine supports.

Comment: I want inherit on PHP level not on doctrine. And also, i mean not of doctrine supported inheritance is suitable for my problem. I want two seperate tables, files and images not some kind of doctrine hybrid something. I tried do it with Attribute Override, but overriding a SequenceGenerator did not work for me. If it worked to you, please post code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a table for file as well as image then use 'Class Table Inheritance' - still read the docs you have been provided with by the other answers. This is suitable for you given your input!

You won't need to define $id again in your Image class and you shouldn't.

Comment: According to doc => Class Table Inheritance is an inheritance mapping strategy where each class in a hierarchy is mapped to several tables: its own table and the tables of all parent classes. The table of a child class is linked to the table of a parent class through a foreign key constraint.

So, no, that's really not what i want. I want 2 full standalone tables, this solution give me just a hybrid that I mentioned above.

Comment: ok, then this is not possible to my knowledge with standard behaviour